# Android app does not start because of Firebase (On Production Release)

Tags: android, firebase

I have 5 app with Firebase SDK installed and they are not working right now. 3 of them are currently on the market. (*I think this is a very important issue. I am considering to remove Firebase from all of my apps*)

In the Firebase website, it is known that the *Crash Service* has an issue. But this kills the app. It seems they did not tested this well. It is the worst bug that it can have.

Note:

- Samsung S4 no problem. (Google Play Services-Version 9.4.52)
- Samsung S6 has this issue. (Google Play Services-Version 9.6.80)

I don't know what to do. I use Google products because I trust them, but this is not what I expected. Here is a copy part from an ANR report that belongs to this problem:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 TimedWaiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x772656c8 self=0x7f83df4a00
  | sysTid=31731 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f87e16fc8
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=3 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fcb72d000-0x7fcb72f000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x0b2c7b14> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x0b2c7b14> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2053)
  at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:372)
  at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleFinder$StageFileApksResultReceiver.a(:com.google.android.gms:476)
  at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleFinder.c(:com.google.android.gms:2458)
  at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.getModuleVersion2(:com.google.android.gms:42)
  at mgq.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:83)
  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eo$a$a.a(unavailable:-1)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eg.a(unavailable:-1)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh.a(unavailable:-1)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ei.a(unavailable:-1)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eg.a(unavailable:-1)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.er.a(unavailable:-1)
  - locked <0x04e8afbd> (a com.google.android.gms.internal.er)
  at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.config.flag.Flags.a(unavailable:-1)
  at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(unavailable:-1)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at q.a.a(unavailable:-1)
  at q.a.a(unavailable:-1)
  at q.a.a(unavailable:-1)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(unavailable:-1)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1789)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1764)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(unavailable:-1)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6762)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6357)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6297)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Since you are saying that this is a **critical** situation, I suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) directly.

Comment: Happening to me as well since 9.4.0.

Comment: Firebase support , did not take it seriously , Probably they did not test the apps with S6. A sentence from their response.  "Galaxy S6 is facing this issue while rest of Android devices are working smoothly, this is likely a hardware issue related to this specific Samsung product."

Comment: Happens to me as well. Not on S6 but other devices:
Moto X (1st Gen) (ghost) 1 9.1%
Nexus 5 (hammerhead) 4 36.4%
Galaxy S4 (ja3g) 3 27.3%
ZP955 1 9.1%
Nexus 4 (mako) 1 9.1%
DROID MAXX 2 (lux) 1 9.1%

Comment: I will try to downgrade to 9.2.1 and also contact Firebase Support.

Comment: My S6 received Play Services 9.6.83 with silent update. And problem fixed... And they noted in the dashboard; " 
We've fixed the issue with Firebase Crash initialization in Google Play Services 9.6.83. Users should receive the update sometime within the next two days. We will conduct an internal investigation of this issue and make appropriate improvements to our systems to prevent or minimize future recurrence."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Firebase support and here is their answer:

```
Hi David,

Thanks for reaching out to us, and sorry if you're having problem with this.

We're currently testing potential fix for this issue. This has been introduced with the Google Play Services 9.6.80, and affects all the apps using the Firebase Crash reporting.
For temporary workaround, you'll have to disable crash reporting on your app. You can remove its entry "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0" on your build.gradle file. 

As posted in our dashboard, all affected customers should expect a new version of Google Play services (9.6.83) by 9/17.
You can follow these links for further updates:
Firebase Status Dashboard
Google Group Discussion
Stack Overflow post
Again, apologies for the inconvenience here, David. 

Regards,
∞Allen
```

So there should be a new version of GPS fixing this tomorrow.

Comment: So what I understood is all the apps who used "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0" library, are not working on devices with Google Play Services-Version 9.6.80. It is one of the worst bug that I have ever seen in my 15 years development life time.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the version of crash library in your project, it depends on version of GPS in your device (which you can't control).